# Why 4k is considered to be standard in file system

Tags: file, operating-system, block

In Operating System, 4k is the default size of a block. When the HDD have more and more capacity to store data; speed of seeking is increased..., Why this standard is not change?

Comment: around s/w pgm based question ?

Comment: oracle database use data block size as default 8Kb. So when i calculate the size of my tables, I found that question.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't always the case, it used to 512 byte/sector. Advanced Format is a format used to store data on HDD that has sector size larger than 512B.

Please read [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2510009?wa=wsignin1.0) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Format)

Comment: I mean the size of block in Operating System level not HDD size of sector. OS often use this 4096 bytes as default